# Find a record using form params in rails "couldn't find error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, destroy

I am new to rails.  I am trying to Find a 'Category' record using a value submitted in a form field.  Since I use Find by params[:id] for url parameters all the time, I thought it would work for form parameters.
This is my error

```
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=

on this line:

 @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

Here is my code

posts_controller.rb

```
def delete
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @category = Category.find(@post.category_id)
  @post_archive = PostArchive.new
end

def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 *@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])* <--the error hits here
 @old_id = params[:post_id]
 @author_id = params[:author_id]
 @followers = Follower.find(post_id: @old_id)
 @post_archive = PostArchive.new

 PostArchive.create!(post_id: @old_id, author_id:   @author_id , removed_by: current_user.id,
  category_id: @category.id, 
  post_created_at: @post.created_at )
 @post.destroy

 @followers.each do |follower|
       ProjectMailer.post_deletion(current_user, @category, @author_id, follower, @old_id ).deliver
  end
  @followers.destroy_all
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Project Deleted' 
end
```

form

```
<%= form_for :delete_post, url: post_destroy_path(@post), method: :delete do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :author_id@post.author_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id, @post.category_id  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id %>
Are you sure you want to delete <%=@post.title %>?
<%=f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I've tested that I can find the param using Categorgy.find(2) and I've tested that the param is actually showing up in the form (it's a hidden field....so I needed to )

server log:

```
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s2pglEj+LUIvZ8OJ0i/sbb3T8hDTcFrqdV0rJqa3c/pihtrMez4S5A8bK3NmoQ/BleKrMRuMTUhZvCwl+00jeQ==", "delete_post"=>{"author_id"=>"21", "category_id"=>"2", "post_id"=>"417"}, "commit"=>"Delete Post", "id"=>"417"}
```

Comment: Try this `@category = Category.find(params[:delete_post][:category_id])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your params, `category_id` is inside `delete_post`

```
Parameters: {"delete_post"=>{"author_id"=>"21", "category_id"=>"2", "post_id"=>"417"}, "commit"=>"Delete Post", "id"=>"417"}
```

It should be

```
@category = Category.find(params[:delete_post][:category_id])
```

Comment: Thank you...I saw that you posted the answer in the comments before the formal answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 *@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])* <--the error hits here
 # change to 
 # *@category = Category.find(params[:delete_post][:category_id])*     
 @old_id = params[:post_id]
 @author_id = params[:author_id]
 @followers = Follower.find(post_id: @old_id)
 @post_archive = PostArchive.new

 PostArchive.create!(post_id: @old_id, author_id:   @author_id , removed_by: current_user.id,
  category_id: @category.id, 
  post_created_at: @post.created_at )
 @post.destroy

 @followers.each do |follower|
       ProjectMailer.post_deletion(current_user, @category, @author_id, follower, @old_id ).deliver
  end
  @followers.destroy_all
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'Project Deleted' 
end
```